# Resize Linux swap /Solaris and give main memory more space?

Tags: swap

For the dual-boot I've allocated about 22 GB space from the disk.
But actually, I'm having about only 10 GB space available for my own usage.

*$fdisk -l* shows me the following:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 223.6 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x07b1bfb7

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048    206847    204800  100M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848 423804927 423598080  202G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       423806974 468860927  45053954 21.5G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       423806976 443924479  20117504  9.6G 83 Linux
/dev/sda6       443926528 468860927  24934400 11.9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

I don't know much about this swap partition, but I really need to have more space on my linux.

Is there an option to take memory from the swap? How? What will be the consciouses?

Answer (score 0):

Since your swap partition appears to be located after other partitions you could delete it, resize you Linux partition (GPARTED) and then create a new swap partition. swap is beeing used when you run of of RAM. There was a rule to use 2 times the swap size compared to your RAM, but if you have enough RAM this might not be neccesary.

All about swap: https://www.linux.com/news/all-about-linux-swap-space

Comment: Please add details about how to use GParted to do it, as well as what needs to be done afterwards to ensure the new swap partition is mounted properly on boot (if needed) and other loose ends.